# Using XQuery with JavaScript in a Meteor enviornment

Tags: javascript, meteor, xquery

Has anyone used XQuery on the server side with Meteor (a JavaScript environment)?

I'm looking to build a XML document server side with JavaScript and XQuery, out of a collation of documents extracted from several collections (Mongodb database). I'll then store this XML document itself in a collection.

Are there any packages/libraries available that will allow for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using oozcitak/xmlbuilder-js (actually a Meteor derivative) for server side xml generation. Works great!

Answer (score 0):

28msec provide an XQuery and JSONiq processor that works with Mongo called Zorba, perhaps that is of interest to you - http://www.zorba.io